# How do I conditionally remove rows based on observation response?

Tags: r, rows, using

I have found many solutions to this question, my problem is I can't get them to work for my dataset.  I am able to build a dummy dataset and the code will work but when I run it with my own data it doesn't.

I am able to build a dummy dataset and the code will work but when I run it with my own data it doesn't. I have tried changed the data type (character vs. factor) and this hasn't changed anything.  The made up code I will post will work, but could someone try to help me figure out why it won't work with my actual data?

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Result <- c("Not Detected", "Not detected", "Negative", "Positive", 
1000, 2000)
df = data.frame(ID, Result)

ID      Result
1   Not Detected            
2   Not detected            
3   Negative            
4   Positive            
5   1000            
6   2000

df2<-df[!(df$Result=="Not detected"),]
df2




ID       Result
1   Not Detected        
3   Negative        
4   Positive        
5   1000        
6   2000
```

It works but I can't figure out why it's not working with my actual data.

Comment: It will be much more helpful if you can post a small example of your real data that does reproduce the error. At the very least, please post the error message...

Comment: How does it not work? What is the output? Try using dplyr. `df3 <- df %>% dplyr::filter(Result !="Not detected")`

Comment: Hi John.  Unfortunately, I can't post the data because it is confidential.  I also do not get an error.  The code will run the variables that I want to remove will remain however.